# setDuration only affects one CALayer when animating multiple CALayers

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to animate a change in position for numerous CALayers simultaneously. Implicit animations seems to work fine, but if I try to explicitly specify a value for the duration properties of each CALayer, only one is animated while the other is changed successfully but without any animation. Here is the code I am working with:

```
CGPoint initialPt = CGPointMake(160.0, 10);
CGPoint pt2 = CGPointMake(160.0, 185.0);
CGPoint pt3 = CGPointMake(160.0, 270.0);

CABasicAnimation *firstAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"postion"];
[firstAnim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:initialPt]];
[firstAnim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt2]];
[firstAnim setDuration:1.0];
[layer1 setPosition:p2];
[layer1 addAnimation:firstAnim forKey:@"Slide"];

CABasicAnimation *secondAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[secondAnim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:initialPt]];
[secondAnim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt3]];
[secondAnim setDuration:1.0];
[layer2 setPosition:p3];
[layer2 addAnimation:secondAnim forKey:@"Slide2"];
```

I've already tried using CATransaction as well but nothing changed. If I comment out the setDuration method, both layers animate the position change without issue, except that they are at a fixed duration. It seems that for some reason setting the animation explicitly muddles things up but I'm lost as to why. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why does the attached code has compile error? Don't you copy the code from your xcode?

Comment: @Danyun Sorry about that! I changed a couple things just for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you type the wrong word!

```
CABasicAnimation *firstAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"postion"]; change the 'postion' to 'position'
```

should be

```
CABasicAnimation *firstAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"]; change the 'postion' to 'position'
```

'postion' to position

Comment: Wow.. I cannot believe that that was the issue. It works now. For some reason Xcode didn't give me a compile error with that keyPath being mispelled. Thanks @Danyun.